# log4j remediation on Jboss Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, jboss, log4j

> Log4j 1.x has reached End of Life in 2015 and is no longer supported. Vulnerabilities reported after August 2015 against Log4j 1.x were not checked and will not be fixed. Users should upgrade to Log4j 2 to obtain security fixes.

Kafka is a software used by the application to communicate between microservices. Kafka in Jboss servers is using log4j 1.x. We need to be able to use 2.x log4j here.

**Vulnerable software installed: Apache Log4j 1.2.17 (/apps/server/standalone/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar)**

All new Kafka version also uses Log4j 1.2.17. Need to remediate this.

JBoss version is jboss-eap-6.4

What is the way?

Answer (score 1):

Log4j2 is not scheduled to be released with Kafka until Kafka 4.0 - [KAFKA-9366](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9366)

Until then, you can try to directly modify the log4j jars yourself to remove vulnerable classes, such as JMSAppender, or replace with reload4j, as only available in recent commits (Kafka 3.1.1 & 3.2) - https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/11743

Seeing as your Jboss is using a version of Kafka several years old now, it might not be possible to upgrade directly without upgrading Jboss itself